# How to pick documents id of which is not contained in array property of all other documents in collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection of documents which has the following shape:

```js
const categorySchema = new Schema<ICategory>({
  title: { type: String, required: true },  
  children: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: categoryModelName }],  
});
```

I want to get all documents id of which is not contained in children array property of all other documents in the collection. How to write such query, if possible?

Comment: Is it true that the entire set of all `children.type` `ObjectId`'s is a subset of the entire set of the documents' `"_id"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write an aggregation pipeline

1. self lookup and create a field which has documents which the current document is a child of
2. If a child of array is empty it means there are no documents where the current document is a child. So filter out those using match

```js
db.categoryCollection.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { from: "categoryCollection", localField: "_id", foreignField: "children", as: "childOf" } },
  { $match: { childOf: { $size: 0 } } },
  { $project: { _id: 1 } }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O0RqYtUi0RU)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, although if the collection is very large the `"$group"` stage may exceed the max allowable memory.  Comments are in the aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      // go through each document
      "_id": null,
      // push all _id's (already unique)
      "ids": {"$push": "$_id"},
      // this will be an array of arrays unfortunately
      "children": {"$addToSet": "$children"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      // don't need _id
      "_id": 0,
      // assign theIds as the output
      "theIds": {
        // set difference = what's in ids but not in children
        "$setDifference": [
          "$ids",
          { // collapse children to a single flat array
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$children",
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sC3FsSGk-UG).

Comment: a bit more complicated than a previous one but never the less interesting one

Comment: It would depend on the collection size, available memory, and having the right indexes, but a performance comparison would be interesting. @DimaKambalin